# PHP Regex email parser only works on mail sent from Live/Hotmail

Tags: php, regex, email

I have a script which uses the following regex to parse emails sent to the server

```
$prefixes = ['/^From:(.*)/', '/^To:(.*)/', '/^Subject:(.*)/'];

while (!feof($email))
{
    while ($line = fgets($email))
    {
        foreach ($prefixes as $prefix)
        {
            if (preg_match($prefix, $line, $matches))
            {
                $data[] = trim($matches[1]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It should find any lines with `From:`, `To:` or `Subject:` and then insert the values into the DB.

However, this only works with emails sent by Microsoft, and doesn't work with Gmail.

I amended the script to log the raw input to a file, and both the emails from Microsoft and Gmail have the same `From:`, `To:` and `Subject:` lines, so I can't figure out why it isn't storing the values correctly.

Comment: the order they come in can be different, not sure if this regex cares about the order?

Comment: @JelleKeizer it shouldn't. I updated the question

Comment: bit of a guess but just in case drop the **^** in case something is in front of the lines

Comment: Go step by step to find where your failure is. For a gmail message, is it opening correctly? Is reading each line correctly? Is it looping over patterns correctly? Is it finding a match correctly? Is it updating $data correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
list($headers, $message) = explode("\n\n", $email);

$header = imap_rfc822_parse_headers($headers);

// You can now access
$header->from;
$header->to;
$header->subject;
```